# Does it hold that $\kappa(A^2) = \kappa(A)^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be invertible and $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be the solution of $Ax=b$.

Let $\kappa(A)$ denote the *condition number* of matrix $A$. Does the following hold?$$\kappa(A^2) = \kappa(A)^2$$

I think that statement is correct. This is the way I have tried to prove it:

$$\kappa(A^2) = \|A^2\| \cdot \|({A^2})^{-1}\| = \|A\| \cdot \|A\| \cdot \|A^{-1}\| \cdot \|A^{-1}\| =\\ \quad\quad\quad= \|A\| \cdot \|A^{-1}\| \cdot \|A\| \cdot \|A^{-1}\| = \kappa(A) \cdot \kappa(A) = \kappa(A)^2$$

**Question:**  Is that correct? Or do I have made a mistake?

Comment: What is $\kappa$?

Comment: A norm is generally not multiplicative, but only submultiplicative.

Comment: $\kappa(A)$ means the condition number of matrix $A$ @barto

Comment: @jublikon And what is the condition number of a matrix?

Comment: Counterexample: Consider $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&100\\0.01&0\end{bmatrix}$. What is $\kappa(A^2)$? What is $\kappa(A)^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since norms are submultiplicative only, you get the inequality
$$
\kappa(A^2) \le \kappa(A)^2.
$$
If $A=A^{-1}$ then $A^2=I$, but $\kappa(A)$ can be larger than one.